# C# initialize object

Tags: c#

The first 3 lines of code works fine..

How can I do the same when using [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) ?

```
// works
Customer MyCustomerx = new Customer();
MyCustomerx.Location[0].place = "New York";
MyCustomerx.Location[1].place = "France";

// problem here
List<Customer> MyCustomer = new List<Customer>
{
 new Customer() { Name= "Me",Location[0].place = "New York" }
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't make sense as stated.

Comment: Give us a bit more information. Does not work is not enough.

Comment: It much easier if pull out from database Complexity..It's like one person have many phone..  such as me have nokia,samsung ,you have lenovo..How do we construct in C# poco ? i'm kinda test and play c# how it work.. from PHP background..there's much possibility can be done there without error..

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What does this have to do with database complexity? Show all relevant code and explain what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no equivalent of that code within object initializers - you can't specify indexers like that. It's slightly unusual that it works even directly... I'd expect to have to *add* to a `Locations` property, rather than there being two already available which I could set an unconventionally-named property on. For example, this would be idiomatic:

```
Customer customer = new Customer {
    Name = "Me",
    Locations = {
        new Location("New York"),
        new Location("France")
    }
};
```

(I'd probably put the name into a constructor parameter, mind you.)

You could then use that within a collection initializer, of course.

Comment: Thanks.. give me some idea... :).. i should create a constructor instead push into another function place..